# Round up time to 1 hour if it's longer than 45 minutes in PHP

Tags: php, date, time, rounding

Basically i need if it's more than or equal to 45 minutes, it must be rounded up. if it's less than that, it must be rounded down

Example :

```
- 18:12 needs to be 18:00
- 18:32 needs to be 18:00
- 18:45 needs to be 19:00
- 18:52 needs to be 19:00
- etc.
```

I'm not sure if that's possible. really need your help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is probably using the Date function PHP has.

```
if((int)date('i', strtotime('18:46')) >= 45){
    echo date('H:00', strtotime('+ 1 hour', strtotime('18:46')));
} else {
    echo '18:46';
}
```

Also could be achieved with string functions but then you'll need to account for midnight notations.

An explode approach could start with:

```
list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', '18:46');
```

A regex approach could start with:

```
(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):(4[5-9]|5\d)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use function like this for 30 minutes

```
function roundToHalfHour($timestring) {
    $minutes = date('i', strtotime($timestring));
    return $minutes - ($minutes % 30);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with DateTime. Add 15 minutes and set minutes and seconds to 0.

```
  $date = '18:12';
  $dt = date_create($date)->modify('+15 Minutes');
  $dt->setTime($dt->format('H'),0,0,0);
```

As a complete test https://3v4l.org/mXBaU

```
$dateArr = ["18:12","18:44","18:45","18:59","19:01"];
foreach($dateArr as $date){
  $dt = date_create($date)->modify('+15 Minutes');
  $dt->setTime($dt->format('H'),0,0,0);

  echo $date.' => '.$dt->format('H:i')."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
18:12 => 18:00
18:44 => 18:00
18:45 => 19:00
18:59 => 19:00
19:01 => 19:00
```